# How to limit content block in octobercms

Tags: octobercms

I have a content block `{% content 'filename.htm' %}` that I display on different pages of the website, however in some parts I want to display only a limited part of the content block.

How do I limit the content block? Is there a way to use `str_words()` or `html_limit()` with it `{% content 'filename.htm' %}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the results of the content block to a variable and then use an appropriate filter / function.

```
{% set content %}
    {% content 'filename.htm' %}
{% endset %}

{{ html_limit(content, 100) }}
```

See also https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/function-html